# How to insert cyrillic and other special chars to SQL Server with SqlCommand c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have created a simple app that helps to translate my websites and applications written in C#. However I don't know how to insert special chars into SQL Server, I used MySql before with PHP. Now I see only `???????` chars when I insert special characters to my database with this command in C#:

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCmd.Connection = connection;
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Translations(TranslationKey,TranslationValue,FromLanguageKey,ToLanguageKey) VALUES (@TranslationKey, @TranslationValue, @FromLanguageKey, @ToLanguageKey)";

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranslationKey", item.TranslationKey);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranslationValue", item.TranslationValue);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FromLanguageKey", item.FromLanguageKey);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToLanguageKey", item.ToLanguageKey);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Some tutorial wrote use N statement, but how can I use it with `Parameters.AddWithValue`?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the most important thing. This:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

is very, very evil. You throw away *all* information you have about any errors that might occur. *If* you catch errors, log and/or show them. Don't throw them away. Code like this will make debugging a nightmare. What you probably wanted to write was:

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Even better: Use the `using` keyword.

---

Now about the minor issue, the localization. You code is correct (except for the point mentioned above), your data types probably aren't.

Since you did not provide an [mcve], one can only guess, but the most probable cause is that you used `varchar` or `text` columns when you should have used `nvarchar` or `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Comment: I used text columns. :S

Comment: @tixovoxi: Use `nvarchar(MAX)` instead. Reason: (1) `text` supports only a single codepage, `ntext` supports Unicode (which is what you want). (2) `text` and `ntext` are deprecated, use `varchar(MAX)` and `nvarchar(MAX)` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and for nvarchar tip :) It solved the problem for me.